# How to find $d,x$ for $\frac{db-c}{a}=x^2$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Given $a,b,c$, big integers with known factors. How to find the integers $d,x$ that will satisfy the equation below?

$$\frac{db-c}{a}=x^2$$

---

I figured the first part:

to find a $d$ that satisfy $\frac{db-c}{a}$ we can say that $db\equiv{c} \pmod{a}$

Then we can set $d$ as $b$ mod inverse $a$ multiply $c$. Now I just need help with figuring out how to make the result of $\frac{db-c}{a}$ a square

Comment: Your posting is at risk of being downvoted/closed because you haven't shown any work.  Please edit your posting to include as much detail as you can re what you have tried and what roadblocks you are encountering.  Please also include **context**: that is, is this problem from a contest, class, or book.  If not from a contest, what theorems or previous problems have you encountered that led up to this problem, that you consider pertinent.

Comment: @user2661923 oh, if this is too trivial then please link me to a wiki page where I can study about this.

Comment: You have misinterpreted by comment.  Not only do I not regard the problem as trivial, I personally do not know how to solve it, or a reference on how to solve it.  My comment was intended merely to indicate that you need to show work and provide context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

You look for integers $ d $ and $ y $ such that

$$bd - ay = c$$

and
$$y=x^2$$

this is a $\color{red}{ Diophantine \;  equation} $ (to google)  which have a solution if $ gcd(a,b)|c$.